# Unable to click link inside iframe

Tags: html, iframe, hyperlink

I need help to click link 'Application Inquiry' using VBA Excel. That link located inside iframe.

Here is the HTML Code:

```
<html>
<head>
<frameset id="mainFrameset" rows="30,*" cols="*" border="0" frameBorder="0" frameSpacing="0">
<frame name="mainTop" src="indexpl.do?task=mainTop" noResize="noresize" scrolling="no">
<frameset id="bottomFrameset" cols="200,*">
<frame name="mainLeftMenu" src="indexpl.do?task=mainLeftMenu" noResize="noresize" scrolling="no">
<html>
<head>
<body class="bodyMenu" onload="">
<div id="Minimum" style="display: inline;">
<div id="Maximum" style="display: none;">
<div id="MenuTreeFrame" style="display: inline;">
<iframe name="NavigasiFrame" width="100%" height="100%" id="NavigasiFrame" src="indexpl.do?task=menuTree" border="0" frameBorder="0" frameSpacing="1" marginWidth="0" marginHeight="0" scrolling="auto" LEFTMARGIN="0" TOPMARGIN="0">
<html>
<head>
<body class="bodyMenu" onload="">
<ul class="menuCapsule">
<ul>
<ul>
<ul>
<li class="menuParent" id="lineB0">
<a onmousedown="javascript:switchMenuHighlightLevel1('lineB',0);" href="bca/action/apppl.do?task=initPage" target="mainHome">
Text - ��::��Application Inquiry
<ul>
<ul>
<frame name="mainHome" src="indexpl.do?task=mainHome" noResize="noresize" scrolling="auto">
```

Any help appreciated. Thanks before.